# Build a questionnaire tree from the flat structure in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a flat json data that I have to handle with TypeScript / Javascript to make it hierarchical, in order to later build a questionnaire.

My typescript classes

```
export class Template
{
    template_id: number;
    template_name: string;
    sections: Section[];
}

export class Section
{
    section_id: number;
    section_name: string;
    fields: Field[];
}

export class Field
{
    field_id: number;
    field_lable : string;
    input_type: InputType;
}

export class InputType
{
    input_type_id: number;
    input_type_name: string;
}
```

Flat data example.
Eventually, it would be list of templates
`templates: Template[];`

```
[
   {
      "Template_id":1,
      "Template_Name":"Enterprise",
      "Section_id":1,
      "Section_Name":"Basic Info",
      "Field_id":1,
      "Field_Label":"Enter Your Name",
      "Input_Type_id":1,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":1,
      "Template_Name":"Enterprise",
      "Section_id":1,
      "Section_Name":"Basic Info",
      "Field_id":2,
      "Field_Label":"Enter Your Address",
      "Input_Type_id":1,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":1,
      "Template_Name":"Enterprise",
      "Section_id":2,
      "Section_Name":"Environment",
      "Field_id":3,
      "Field_Label":"Do you believe in environment",
      "Input_Type_id":3,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Checkbox"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":1,
      "Template_Name":"Enterprise",
      "Section_id":3,
      "Section_Name":"Transfer",
      "Field_id":4,
      "Field_Label":"Select prefer transfer modes",
      "Input_Type_id":2,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Dropdown"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":2,
      "Template_Name":"RRR",
      "Section_id":4,
      "Section_Name":"Basic Info",
      "Field_id":5,
      "Field_Label":"Enter Your Name",
      "Input_Type_id":1,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":2,
      "Template_Name":"RRR",
      "Section_id":4,
      "Section_Name":"Basic Info",
      "Field_id":6,
      "Field_Label":"Enter Your Address",
      "Input_Type_id":1,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":2,
      "Template_Name":"RRR",
      "Section_id":5,
      "Section_Name":"GPO",
      "Field_id":7,
      "Field_Label":"Select names of GPOs",
      "Input_Type_id":2,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Dropdown"
   },
   {
      "Template_id":2,
      "Template_Name":"RRR",
      "Section_id":6,
      "Section_Name":"Unit",
      "Field_id":8,
      "Field_Label":"Enter name of your unit",
      "Input_Type_id":1,
      "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
   }
]
```

I would like to know if there are any functions I can use from lodash or similar libraries

Expected Output:

```
[
   {
      "Template_id":1,
      "Template_Name":"Enterprise",
      "Sections":[
         {
            "Section_id":1,
            "Section_Name":"Basic Info",
            "Fields":[
               {
                  "Field_id":1,
                  "Field_Label":"Enter Your Name",
                  "Input_Type_id":1,
                  "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
               },
               {
                  "Field_id":2,
                  "Field_Label":"Enter Your Address",
                  "Input_Type_id":1,
                  "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Section_id":2,
            "Section_Name":"Environment",
            "Fields":[
               {
                  "Field_id":3,
                  "Field_Label":"Do you believe in environment",
                  "Input_Type_id":3,
                  "Input_Type_Name":"Checkbox"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Template_id":2,
      "Template_Name":"RRR",
      "Sections":[
         {
            "Section_id":4,
            "Section_Name":"Basic Info",
            "Fields":[
               {
                  "Field_id":5,
                  "Field_Label":"Enter Your Name",
                  "Input_Type_id":1,
                  "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
               },
               {
                  "Field_id":6,
                  "Field_Label":"Enter Your Address",
                  "Input_Type_id":1,
                  "Input_Type_Name":"Text"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Section_id":5,
            "Section_Name":"GPO",
            "Fields":[
               {
                  "Field_id":7,
                  "Field_Label":"Select names of GPOs",
                  "Input_Type_id":2,
                  "Input_Type_Name":"Dropdown"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an convenient function. However, you can use native `reduce` method to make the data nested and each class method can have its own init function then you can recursively call it

```js
const r = data.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item.Template_id] = result[item.Template_id] || { id: item.Template_id, name: item.Template_Name }
    result[item.Template_id][item.Section_id] = result[item.Template_id][item.Section_id] || { id: item.Section_id, name: item.Section_Name}
    result[item.Template_id][item.Section_id][item.Field_id] = result[item.Template_id][item.Section_id][item.Field_id] || { id: item.Field_id, label: item.Field_Label}
    result[item.Template_id][item.Section_id][item.Field_id][item.Input_Type_id] = result[item.Template_id][item.Section_id][item.Field_id][item.Input_Type_id] || { id: item.Input_Type_id, name: item.Input_Type_Name }

    return result
}, {})
```

This would give the result like this

```json
{
  "1": {
    "1": {
      "1": {
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Text"
        },
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Enter Your Name"
      },
      "2": {
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Text"
        },
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Enter Your Address"
      },
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Basic Info"
    },
    "2": {
      "3": {
        "3": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Checkbox"
        },
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Do you believe in environment"
      },
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Environment"
    },
    "3": {
      "4": {
        "2": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Dropdown"
        },
        "id": 4,
        "label": "Select prefer transfer modes"
      },
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Transfer"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Enterprise"
  },
  "2": {
    "4": {
      "5": {
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Text"
        },
        "id": 5,
        "label": "Enter Your Name"
      },
      "6": {
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Text"
        },
        "id": 6,
        "label": "Enter Your Address"
      },
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Basic Info"
    },
    "5": {
      "7": {
        "2": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Dropdown"
        },
        "id": 7,
        "label": "Select names of GPOs"
      },
      "id": 5,
      "name": "GPO"
    },
    "6": {
      "8": {
        "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Text"
        },
        "id": 8,
        "label": "Enter name of your unit"
      },
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Unit"
    },
    "id": 2,
    "name": "RRR"
  }
}
```

Afterwards, you can iterate each template data and let the Template class to deserialize it. Within Template class, it can recursively call Section, Field and Input

Comment: I've added my expected output. I will try your method to see this can be achieved. Thanks!